# Having trouble running my code example of polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I copied a bicycle example and want to change it to a car example but I can't get the extended class Mountainbike of the class PolyCar to run.  If I comment out Mountainbike, PolyCar will run.  Can anyone tell me why the program does not recognize Mountainbike

Here is the TestCar program used to run my PolyCar program

```
//import PolyCar.MountainBike;
//import PolyCar.RoadBike;

public class TestCars {
      public static void main(String[] args){
        PolyCar bike01, bike02, bike03;

        bike01 = new PolyCar(20, 10, 1);
        bike02 = new MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");
//      bike03 = new RoadBike(40, 20, 8, 23);

        bike01.printDescription();
        bike02.printDescription();
//      bike03.printDescription();
      }
    }
```

Here is my PolyCar Code

```
public class PolyCar {

    // the PolyCar class has three fields
    public int cadence;
    public int gear;
    public int speed;

    // the PolyCar class has one constructor
    public PolyCar(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;
    }

    // the PolyCar class has four methods
    public void setCadence(int newValue) {
        cadence = newValue;
    }

    public void setGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
    }

    public void applyBrake(int decrement) {
        speed -= decrement;
    }

    public void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed += increment;
    }
public void printDescription(){
    System.out.println("\nBike is " + "in gear " + this.gear
        + " with a cadence of " + this.cadence +
        " and travelling at a speed of " + this.speed + ". ");
}
public class MountainBike extends PolyCar {
    private String suspension;

    public MountainBike(
               int startCadence,
               int startSpeed,
               int startGear,
               String suspensionType){
        super(startCadence,
              startSpeed,
              startGear);
        this.setSuspension(suspensionType);
    }

    public String getSuspension(){
      return this.suspension;
    }

    public void setSuspension(String suspensionType) {
        this.suspension = suspensionType;
    }

    public void printDescription() {
        super.printDescription();
        System.out.println("The " + "MountainBike has a" +
            getSuspension() + " suspension.");
    }
} 
public class RoadBike extends PolyCar{
    // In millimeters (mm)
    private int tireWidth;

    public RoadBike(int startCadence,
                    int startSpeed,
                    int startGear,
                    int newTireWidth){
        super(startCadence,
              startSpeed,
              startGear);
        this.setTireWidth(newTireWidth);
    }

    public int getTireWidth(){
      return this.tireWidth;
    }

    public void setTireWidth(int newTireWidth){
        this.tireWidth = newTireWidth;
    }

    public void printDescription(){
        super.printDescription();
        System.out.println("The RoadBike" + " has " + getTireWidth() +
            " MM tires.");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are the import statements supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Extract each class to its own class file.

Answer (score 1):

You have `MountainBike` and `RoadBike` encapsulated within the `PolyCar` class; they should be in separate class files. Your solution is as simple as moving the last curly brace to conclude the `PolyCar` class before declaring the other two subclasses.

At the moment you have:

```
public class PolyCar
{
    ...
    public class MountainBike extends PolyCar{
        ...
    }

    public class RoadBike extends PolyCar{
        ...
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
class PolyCar {
    ...  
} 

class RoadBike extends PolyCar{
    ....
}

class RoadBike extends PolyCar{
    ...
}
```

Working TutorialsPoint example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdkV0cVo4Y0hUSWM)

Answer (score 0):

You have the MountainBike and the RoadBike in the scope of your PolyCar class.

Logic thing to do will be to take them out (put a brace before the MountainBike definition and remove the last one after the RoadBike class). Or make the MountainBike and RoadBike classes static and initialize them like bike02 = new PolyCar.MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");

Second option is bad in my opinion because there is no logic behind putting them as nested classes, as you try to accomplish inheritance & polymorphism <s>and nested *represents a kind of "composition" relationship.*</s>

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.  Got my program running

Comment: I change the place of the bracket

Comment: @Elmore You're welcome. Don't forget to support by validating the answer if the post is what you were expecting ;)